# xWebAdministration does not appear in Get-DscResource (PowerShell)

Tags: powershell, dsc

This is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26676627/powershell-how-to-install-the-dsc-resource-kit-wave-8-modules):

I downloaded [xWebAdminstration](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/xWebAdministration-Module-3c8bb6be).
I modified my environment variable PSModulePath in Windows (I'm testing/developing on Win 7).

In C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules, I have 7 directories, for example the first is MSFT_xiisModule.

My environment variable PSModulePath is set to:
%SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\PowerShell\Modules\

I ran this:

```
Write-Host "`$env:PSModulePath=$($env:PSModulePath)"
Write-Host "`$env:ProgramFiles=$($env:ProgramFiles)"
Write-Host "`$CurrentValue=$CurrentValue"
Write-Host "`$PSVersionTable.PSVersion=$($PSVersionTable.PSVersion)"
Get-Module -ListAvailable
Write-Host "`n`n==== DscResources ====="
Get-DscResource | Select Name, Properties | ft -AutoSize
```

and this is the output (which shows the modules are being found as module, but not as DscResources):

```
 $env:PSModulePath=C:\Users\neal.walters\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerS
hell\Modules;C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Serv
er\120\Tools\PowerShell\Modules\;c:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\
$env:ProgramFiles=C:\Program Filession=4.0


        Directory: C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules


    ModuleType Version    Name                                ExportedCommands                       
    ---------- -------    ----                                ----------------                       
    Script     0.0        MSFT_xIisModule                     {Get-TargetResource, Set-TargetResou...
    Script     0.0        MSFT_xWebApplication                {Get-TargetResource, Set-TargetResou...
    Script     0.0        MSFT_xWebAppPool                    {Get-TargetResource, Set-TargetResou...
    Script     0.0        MSFT_xWebConfigKeyValue             {Get-TargetResource, Set-TargetResou...
    Script     0.0        MSFT_xWebDeploy                     {Get-TargetResource, Set-TargetResou...
    Script     0.0        MSFT_xWebsite                       {Get-TargetResource, Set-TargetResou...
    Script     0.0        MSFT_xWebVirtualDirectory           {Get-TargetResource, Set-TargetResou...


        Directory: C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules


    ModuleType Version    Name                                ExportedCommands                       
    ---------- -------    ----                                ----------------                       
    Manifest   1.0.0.0    AppLocker                           {Set-AppLockerPolicy, Get-AppLockerP...
    Manifest   1.0.0.0    BitsTransfer                        {Add-BitsFile, Remove-BitsTransfer, ...
    Manifest   1.0.0.0    CimCmdlets                          {Get-CimAssociatedInstance, Get-CimC...
    Script     1.0.0.0    ISE                                 {New-IseSnippet, Import-IseSnippet, ...
    Manifest   3.0.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Diagnostics    {Get-WinEvent, Get-Counter, Import-C...
    Manifest   3.0.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Host           {Start-Transcript, Stop-Transcript}    
    Manifest   3.1.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Management     {Add-Content, Clear-Content, Clear-I...
    Manifest   3.0.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Security       {Get-Acl, Set-Acl, Get-PfxCertificat...
    Manifest   3.1.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility        {Format-List, Format-Custom, Format-...
    Manifest   3.0.0.0    Microsoft.WSMan.Management          {Disable-WSManCredSSP, Enable-WSManC...
    Binary     1.0        PSDesiredStateConfiguration         {Set-DscLocalConfigurationManager, S...
    Script     1.0.0.0    PSDiagnostics                       {Disable-PSTrace, Disable-PSWSManCom...
    Binary     1.1.0.0    PSScheduledJob                      {New-JobTrigger, Add-JobTrigger, Rem...
    Manifest   2.0.0.0    PSWorkflow                          {New-PSWorkflowExecutionOption, New-...
    Manifest   1.0.0.0    PSWorkflowUtility                   Invoke-AsWorkflow                      
    Manifest   1.0.0.0    TroubleshootingPack                 {Get-TroubleshootingPack, Invoke-Tro...
    Manifest   1.0.0.0    WebAdministration                   {Start-WebCommitDelay, Stop-WebCommi...


        Directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\PowerShell\Modules


    ModuleType Version    Name                                ExportedCommands                       
    ---------- -------    ----                                ----------------                       
    Manifest   1.0        SQLASCMDLETS                        {Add-RoleMember, Backup-ASDatabase, ...
    Manifest   1.0        SQLPS                               {Backup-SqlDatabase, Add-SqlAvailabi...


        Directory: c:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules


    ModuleType Version    Name                                ExportedCommands                       
    ---------- -------    ----                                ----------------                       
    Script     0.0        MSFT_xIisModule                     {Get-TargetResource, Set-TargetResou...
    Script     0.0        MSFT_xWebApplication                {Get-TargetResource, Set-TargetResou...
    Script     0.0        MSFT_xWebAppPool                    {Get-TargetResource, Set-TargetResou...
    Script     0.0        MSFT_xWebConfigKeyValue             {Get-TargetResource, Set-TargetResou...
    Script     0.0        MSFT_xWebDeploy                     {Get-TargetResource, Set-TargetResou...
    Script     0.0        MSFT_xWebsite                       {Get-TargetResource, Set-TargetResou...
    Script     0.0        MSFT_xWebVirtualDirectory           {Get-TargetResource, Set-TargetResou...


    ==== DscResources =====



    Name           Properties                                          
    ----           ----------                                          
    File           {DestinationPath, Attributes, Checksum, Contents...}
    Archive        {Destination, Path, Checksum, DependsOn...}         
    Environment    {Name, DependsOn, Ensure, Path...}                  
    Group          {GroupName, Credential, DependsOn, Description...}  
    Log            {Message, DependsOn}                                
    Package        {Name, Path, ProductId, Arguments...}               
    Registry       {Key, ValueName, DependsOn, Ensure...}              
    Script         {GetScript, SetScript, TestScript, Credential...}   
    Service        {Name, BuiltInAccount, Credential, DependsOn...}    
    User           {UserName, DependsOn, Description, Disabled...}     
    WindowsFeature {Name, Credential, DependsOn, Ensure...}            
    WindowsProcess {Arguments, Path, Credential, DependsOn...}
```

Comment: The page for that resource says `This module requires the latest version of PowerShell (v4.0, which ships in Windows 8.1 or Windows Server 2012R2). It also requires IIS features.` I see that you have PS 4 installed from your output. Do you also have IIS features installed? Since not all IIS features are available on Windows 7, I wonder if maybe it's not possible to use this on a client OS. Unfortunately they don't seem to specify which features.

Comment: I do have IIS installed; I'll have to zoom-in on the features, but basically I can open IIS Admin and setup websites.  I'm guessing that if you download Powershell 4.0 it doesn't matter what OS you are on.

Comment: Here's something interesting. I ran your code on my system (Windows 8.1), and I noticed that in the `Get-Module` call, all of the modules with DSC resources show a version of 0.0 in your call, but in mine they show real versions. That could be a clue as to what's happening. `Get-DscResource` does show the resources on my system. What is your execution policy? These are script modules so you need to be able to run scripts to load them.

Comment: Always run -unrestricted.  Does the fourth line of your xIisModuleDesigner.ps1  file show this: 
  $classVersion = "1.0.0"  
In that other post I referred to, he has "DSCResources" in his directory structure.  The install said just to unpzip files to c:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\.  I did try putting them under DSCResources but didn't see any difference.  Is that foldername required to get DSC to work, i.e. to go beyond just being a module to being a real DSC?  I have a Win 2008/R2 "dev" server, I could try it there.

Comment: Yes, I have the same version of that file. The `DSCResources` folder is absolutely required. The directory structure is very important. Your path should be something like this (for an example file): `C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\xWebAdministration\DSCResources\MSFT_xWebApplication\MSFT_xWebApplication.psm1`

Comment: Here is a good reference for that: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2013/12/05/how-to-deploy-and-discover-windows-powershell-desired-state-configuration-resources.aspx

Comment: Okay, I should have taken the doc more literally.  I figured I didn't need hte .docx file and the Examples, so I only unzipped the DSCResources.  I think it was the missing xWebAdministration\xWebAdministration.psd1, along with the structure that was the problem.  Thanks, do you want me to answer, or do you want the credit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the comments, I am seeing now that the problem is path structure. In your output, you have this:

```
Directory: c:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules


ModuleType Version    Name                                ExportedCommands                       
---------- -------    ----                                ----------------                       
Script     0.0        MSFT_xIisModule                     {Get-TargetResource, Set-TargetResou...
Script     0.0        MSFT_xWebApplication                {Get-TargetResource, Set-TargetResou...
Script     0.0        MSFT_xWebAppPool                    {Get-TargetResource, Set-TargetResou...
Script     0.0        MSFT_xWebConfigKeyValue             {Get-TargetResource, Set-TargetResou...
Script     0.0        MSFT_xWebDeploy                     {Get-TargetResource, Set-TargetResou...
Script     0.0        MSFT_xWebsite                       {Get-TargetResource, Set-TargetResou...
Script     0.0        MSFT_xWebVirtualDirectory           {Get-TargetResource, Set-TargetResou...
```

Your directory structure should look like this:

`C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\xWebAdministration\DSCResources\`

Within there, *that's* where the `MSFT_x*` directories go. This is also why the versions are all listed as `0.0`.

Make sure you've got the parent directory for the module (`xWebAdministration`), which should contain at minimum a `.psd1` (module manifest) and a `DSCResources` folder, in which is a folder for each resource which contains a `.psm1` and an `.mof` file.

See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2013/12/05/how-to-deploy-and-discover-windows-powershell-desired-state-configuration-resources.aspx for a visual.

Comment: This structure is actually very similar to the way WordPress plugins are installed.

Comment: That's an interesting observation; never thought about it that way before.