# xWebAdministration resources does not appear in Get-DscResource

Tags: powershell, dsc

I'm trying to get a basic DSC configuration going on a Windows Server 2012 R2 VM, but when I run Get-DscResource, none of the xWebAdministration resources appear in the list.

When I run

```
Get-Module -ListAvailable -Name x*
```

I get the following

```
Directory: C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules


ModuleType Version    Name                                ExportedCommands
---------- -------    ----                                ----------------
Manifest   1.3.2      xWebAdministration
```

Looking at other modules exportedCommands should not be empty.

Any suggestion on how I can get this fixed?

#### What I've done

I've downloaded [version 1.3.2](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/xWebAdministration-Module-3c8bb6be) and have extracted it to C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules

Found this [xWebAdministration does not appear in Get-DscResource (PowerShell)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27989105/xwebadministration-does-not-appear-in-get-dscresource-powershell) but structure is correct.

Comment: So do you have dir structure like this? C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules

Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
d----         1/04/2015  11:28 AM            MSFT_xIisModule
d----         1/04/2015  11:28 AM            MSFT_xWebApplication
d----         1/04/2015  11:28 AM            MSFT_xWebAppPool
d----         1/04/2015  11:28 AM            MSFT_xWebConfigKeyValue
d----         1/04/2015  11:28 AM            MSFT_xWebDeploy
d----         1/04/2015  11:28 AM            MSFT_xWebsite

Comment: That didn't come out too well. Do you have the MSFT_ directories in the Modules directory?

Comment: @JanChrbolka no I have the MSFT_* directories under C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\xWebAdministration\DSCResources

Comment: I see, my bad, I had them in the wrong dir structure and now I have the same issues as you :) Better leave this to somebody more who knows more about DSC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Installing [WMF 5.0 Preview](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=45883) fixed the issue.

I reverted back to a snapshot and made sure my VM was fully up-to-date, which also fixed the issue. So seems like I was missing an update.